# Strawberry Shake Graphql and WinForms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, strawberryshake

I created one server with HotChocolate. Now, I want to create Winforms application, but I don't know how to implement GraphQL in winforms.
Do anybody know how to use Strawberry Shake GraphQL in Winforms?
Sorry, I'm new in c#.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.